# Nested SELECT with LEFT JOIN - TypeORM, NestJS and PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am currently working on one feature that should implement Many-To-Many relationship with custom properties using NestJS and TypeORM.

**Tech used**

- NestJS
- PostgreSQL
- TypeORM

**Tables info**

Skill Table

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | .NET |
| 2 | Azure |
| 3 | JS |

Resume Table

| id | Name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | resume-1 | resume-1 |
| 2 | resume-2 | resume-2 |
| 3 | resume-3 | resume-3 |

Pivot Table

| id | resumeId | skillId | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Advanced |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Advanced |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | Advanced |

**Expected result**

1. Return all resumes even if no skills are present
2. Filter query if search params are passed

**The challenge**

The second point from expected results is pretty much clear. But, the first point is very difficult to handle with TypeORM.

Since it is a Many-To-Many one would expect to start with the Pivot Table and **right join** the two tables. That will result in getting all of the records and setting NULL for the records (skill columns) that have no skills.

Something like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM pivot_table pt
RIGHT JOIN skill s ON s.id = pt.skillId
RIGHT JOIN resume r ON r.id = pt.resumeId
```

Result

| id | resumeId | skillId | level | s_id | s_name | r_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Advanced | 1 | .NET | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Advanced | 2 | Azure | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | Advanced | 3 | JS | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | null | null | null | null | null |

**TypeORM**

*TypeORM does not support right join*

[Relevant StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690181/typeorm-how-to-do-a-right-join-and-select)

[Valid TypeORM argument - Github issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/887#issuecomment-329513821)

**Solution**

```
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM "resume") R1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM "resume_to_skill") R2 ON (R1.ID = R2."resumeId") 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM "skill") S1 ON (S1.ID = R2."skillId")
```

**Models**

Resume.entity.ts

```js
@Entity()
@Unique(['slug'])
export class Resume {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  slug: string;

  @OneToMany(() => ResumeToSkill, (resumeToSkill) => resumeToSkill.resume)
  resumeToSkill!: ResumeToSkill[];
}
```

Skill.entity.ts

```js
@Entity()
export class Skill {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => ResumeToSkill, (resumeToSkill) => resumeToSkill.skill)
  resumeToSkill!: ResumeToSkill[];
}
```

ResumeToSkill.entity.ts

```js
@Entity()
@Unique(['resume', 'skill'])
export class ResumeToSkill {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Resume, (resume) => resume.resumeToSkill, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  resume: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Skill, (skill) => skill.resumeToSkill, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  skill: string;

  @Column()
  level: string;
}
```

**Request**

I tried researching on how to create such a query using TypeORM, but no result. I struggle to figure out how to start with the "resume" table and then left join the subqueries. I would really appreciate it If you could **point** me to the right direction or help me resolve this.

Comment: I think you are overthinking the solution query. It can be simplified to: `SELECT * FROM "resume" R1 LEFT JOIN "resume_to_skill" R2 ON R1.ID = R2."resumeId" LEFT JOIN "skill" S1 ON S1.ID = R2."skillId"`.

Comment: Yeah, you are certainly correct about that. Thanks! The biggest problem is not the PostgreSQL query, but the TypeORM equivalent. Since the Many-To-Many contains the "custom property - level" the models are created with OneToMany and ManyToOne. Which means - Resume (and Skill) table has resumeToSkil OneToMany rel towards ResumeToSkill pivot table, while ResumeToSkill pivot table has ManyToOne on both Resume and Skill. And I couldn't figure out the way to create the queryBuilder in such a way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
//Entity

@Entity('resume')
@Unique(['slug'])
export class Resume {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  slug: string;

  @OneToMany(() => ResumeToSkill, (resumeToSkill) => resumeToSkill.resume)
  resumeToSkill!: ResumeToSkill[];
}

@Entity('skill')
export class Skill {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => ResumeToSkill, (resumeToSkill) => resumeToSkill.skill)
  resumeToSkill!: ResumeToSkill[];
}

@Entity('resume_to_skill')
@Unique(['resume', 'skill'])
export class ResumeToSkill {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Resume, (resume) => resume.resumeToSkill, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  resume: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Skill, (skill) => skill.resumeToSkill, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  skill: string;

  @Column()
  level: string;
}
```

```
// Service

.....
constructor(
    // add repository Resume 
    @InjectRepository(Resume)
    private _repo: Repository<Resume>,
  ) {}
.....
async findAll() {
    const entity = await this._repo
      .createQueryBuilder('resume')
      .select(
        'resume.id as rs_id, resume.name as rs_name, resume.slug, rts.*, rs.*',
      )
      .leftJoin('resume.resumeToSkill', 'rts')
      .leftJoin('rts.skill', 'rs')
      .getRawMany();

    return entity;
}
```

Result: [image: result]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! This could work. i am getting this error now **"TypeORMError: Relation with property path resumeToSkill in entity was not found."** which is weird, it's as if there is no resumeToSkill OneToMany in the **resume.entity.ts** and **skill.entity.ts** I am not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: Hi there, FYI i have revised my answer by adding the entity. Please check this out and retry. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi there! Thanks, for your responses. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem, even though i have the same entities and the same way of querying. I think i'll have to use the .query() from TypeORM. I'll try something else, but the task time is ticking and I have to move on. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there, I want to notify you that I managed to resolve this problem. Your comment helped a lot. It was a problem with the repository at the end. Everything is fine now. Thanks, again!